# flutter youtube error Domain: XCDYouTubeVideoErrorDomain at ios

Tags: flutter, youtube

my pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  responsive_container: ^0.0.1
  flutter_html: ^0.10.4
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  flutter_pagewise: ^1.2.3
  share: ^0.6.3+6
  flutter_youtube: ^1.1.6
  loader_search_bar: ^1.0.3+3
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.4
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.2
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^5.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
  rate_my_app: ^0.4.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
```

flutter youtube plugin  working good at android same videos

but at ios i get error

```
[XCDYouTubeKit] Video operation finished with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCDYouTubeVideoErrorDomain error -2.)
Domain: XCDYouTubeVideoErrorDomain
Code:   -2
User Info: {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed with me by luck

i comment

```
platform :ios, '10.3'
```

at Podfile

i was uncomment it

becouse that error

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

any way that's working now at ios too

am happy to share it with all